# Trying to iterate through folders and take recursive actions on each file

Tags: powershell, recursion, filesystems, data-management

I'm trying to build a script that I can use to delete old files based on Last Accessed date. As part of the script I want to interrogate each sub folder, find files not accessed in the last X days, create a log in the same folder of the files found and record file details in the log then delete the files.

What I think I need is a nested loop, loop 1 will get each subfolder (`Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse`) then for each folder found a second loop checks all files for last accessed date and if outside the limit will append the file details to a logfile in the folder (for user reference) and also to a master logfile (for IT Admin)

loop 1 is working as expected and getting the subfolders, but I cannot get the inner loop to recurse through the objects in the folder, I'm trying to use `Get-ChildItem` inside the first loop, is this the correct approach?

Code sample below, I have added pseudo to demo the logic, its really the loops I need help with:

```
# Set variables
$FolderPath = "E:TEST_G"
$ArchiveLimit = 7
$ArchiveDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$ArchiveLimit)
$MasterLogFile = "C:\Temp\ArchiveLog $(Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd).csv"

# Loop 1 - Iterate through each subfolder of $FolderPath
Get-ChildItem -Path $FolderPath -Directory -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    # Loop 2 - Check each file in the Subfolder and if Last Access is past
    # $ArchiveDate take Action
    Get-ChildItem -Path $_.DirectoryName | where {
        $_.LastAccessTime -le $ArchiveDate
    } | ForEach-Object {
        # Check if FolderLogFile Exists, if not create it
        # Append file details to folder Log
        # Append File & Folder Details to Master Log 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating a bit:

```
#Set Variables
$FolderPath = "E:\TEST_G"
$ArchiveLimit = 7
$ArchiveDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$ArchiveLimit)
$MasterLogFile = "C:\Temp\ArchiveLog $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).csv"
If (!(Test-Path $MasterLogFile)) {New-Item $MasterLogFile -Force}

Get-ChildItem -Path $FolderPath -File -Recurse |
  Where-Object { $_.LastAccessTime -lt $ArchiveDate -and
                 $_.Extension -ne '.log' } |
  ForEach-Object {
    $FolderLogFile = Join-Path $_.DirectoryName 'name.log'
    Add-Content -Value "details" -Path $FolderLogFile,$MasterLogFile

    Try {
      Remove-Item $_ -Force -EA Stop
    } Catch {
      Add-Content -Value "Unable to delete item! [$($_.Exception.GetType().FullName)] $($_.Exception.Message)"`
                  -Path $FolderLogFile,$MasterLogFile
    }
  }
```

Edit:
Multiple recursive loops are unnecessary since you're already taking a recursive action in the pipeline.  It's powerful enough to do the processing without having to take extra action.  `Add-Content` from the other answer is an excellent solution over `Out-File` as well, so I replaced mine.

One note, though, `Add-Content`'s `-Force` flag does not create the folder structure like `New-Item`'s will.  That is the reason for the line under the `$MasterLogFile` declaration.

Comment: Care to explain why the OPs code was incorrect and how this helps?

Comment: He doesn't need multiple recursive loops, just using the pipeline natively is powerful enough.

Comment: Super. Now edit that into your answer so it doesnt just look like a code dump.

Comment: Thanks TheIncorrigible1 your solution does exactly what I needed.

Comment: One final question on this, I'm getting errors when I enable the Try block to remove-item, $_ does not seem to return the target file, instead the system is trying to find the file in c:\winodws\stystem32 (default path). Is there a reason why the $_ has lost the object? as it is still in the for-each loop? Do I need to assign it to a variable ($_.Fullname etc.) instead?

Comment: `$_` will still be referring to the current object.  What changes did you make to the blocks?

Comment: Hi, I took the try block as above. My code is as follows...                 #Step that attempts the deletion
    Try {
      Remove-Item $_ -Force -EA Stop
    } Catch {
      Add-Content -Value "Unable to delete item! [$($_.Exception.GetType().FullName)] $($_.Exception.Message)"`
                  -Path $FolderLogFile,$MasterLogFile
    } the error I get in log is ........                                       Unable to delete item! [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException] Cannot find path 'C:\Windows\system32\part1.mp4' because it does not exist.

Comment: You can try `Set-Location $FolderPath` and use `-Path .` to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

Your nested loop doesn't need recursion (the outer loop already takes care of that). Just process the files in each folder (make sure you exclude the folder log):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $FolderPath -Directory -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $FolderLogFile = Join-Path $_.DirectoryName 'FolderLog.log'
    Get-ChildItem -Path $_.DirectoryName -File | Where-Object {
        $_.LastAccessTime -le $ArchiveDate -and
        $_.FullName -ne $FolderLogFile
    } | ForEach-Object {
        'file details' | Add-Content $FolderLogFile
        'file and folder details' | Add-Content $MasterLogFile
        Remove-Item $_.FullName -Force
    }
}
```

You don't need to test for the existence of the folder log file, because `Add-Content` will automatically create it if it's missing.

Comment: Thanks for taking to review and respond Ansgar, your point about nested loops helped set me on the right track.

Comment: @downvoter Care to explain what you consider wrong about this answer?